# How to export datagridview and treeview data to excel in c#?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, treeview, closedxml

I have one datagridview and one treeview in my form.

I have a problem like where I need to show the details of items carried in each container and exporting it to excel

Here is an example,

Several items are carried in container and moved to another location, whenever it is moved I need to track the number of containers and list of items carried in each container. This is said to be one trip.

I am displaying all the trip details in datagridview and when the user clicks on a single row, corresponding to that trip id, the container details are populated in treeview.

screenshot is shown below

http://postimg.org/image/j8a6mj5mz/

How do I export these data of datagridview and treeview to excel?

I am using closedXML SDK to export datatable to excel.

But I want the treeview data to be shown corresponding to each trip details row. 
After few research I came across something like pivottable. Is pivottable the correct solution? I don't have any idea, How do I achieve this in this SDK? Is there any alternative SDK to achieve this?

Comment: https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pivot%20Table%20example

Comment: @Raidri Is pivot table the correct solution?

Comment: Seriously I don't want pivot table. I just want to display the data in excel. How do I do that?